# How to manage multiple versions of binary dependencies in TFS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, release-management, alm

I'm managing release process for couple of projects that target external API. Typical scenario is that a single solution targets a particular version, say v1, of 3rd party runtime in a production and newer version (v2) in development phase. I have to maintain dependencies for v1 for production support but also  v2 for a DEV branch. Those scenarios may even go more complex depends on the rollout plan.

I tried branching + nuget but the problem is API I use is huge and it is hard to build a scope of a nuget package. Putting everything into one package makes no sense for smaller projects and on the other hand depending on what features we integrate, combination of DLLs may vary a lot and they are not nicely separated into closed concerns.

On top of it, usually we have multiple solutions that use those APIs.

I was thinking about building API version repository in TFS in some form

```
- myAPI
        |- v1
        |- v2
        |- v3
```

Is there a way to configure a build process to look inside a server for referenced DLL files depending on a build setup? I can maintain multiple builds in the system obviously but I don't know how to provide referenced files location for each individual build.

Comment: Not sure if you have the book Professional Team Foundation Server but it contains some useful information for your scenario. The book contains a chapter on Common Version Control Scenarios with a subsection on Third-Party Source Code/Dependencies

Comment: @WouterdeKort can you please provide a link or author?

Comment: Of course! This is the 2013 edition that's just released: http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Team-Foundation-Server-2013/dp/1118836340/ I read the chapter I referred to in the 2012 edition but according to Amazon it's also in the 2013 one. It's a highly recommended book!